# How do I make values not repeat in SQL GROUP BY when I add the date?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, subquery

I started with SQL recently and I'm a bit confused. I want to apply this query, but add a date column:

```
SELECT CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) AS Full_name,
            SUM(p.amount) Pay_amount
FROM customer c
JOIN payment p ON c.customer_id = p.customer_id
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

But whenever I add the date column, the result changes completely to repeating customers with different dates.

```
SELECT CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) AS Full_name,
            SUM(p.amount) Pay_amount, 
            payment_date
FROM customer c
JOIN payment p ON c.customer_id = p.customer_id
GROUP BY 1, 3
ORDER BY 2 DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

EDIT: Here is the sample database I'm using: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-sample-database/

Comment: When there is more than one date, what value do you want?  Also tag with the database you are using.

Comment: Your GROUP BY says you want each Full_name/payment_date combination. If you want just one payment_date for a Full_name, you have to decide which one (e.g. first, or last.)

Comment: You might want to look into PostgreSql Functions like Grouping Sets. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUPING-SETS

Answer (score 1):

You can use an aggregation function:

```
SELECT CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) AS Full_name,
       SUM(p.amount) AS Pay_amount, 
       MAX(p.payment_date)
FROM customer c JOIN
     payment p
     ON c.customer_id = p.customer_id
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Thanks, everyone. I realize that my question was stupid.